# Getting selected option that does not have selected attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

So if this is my example code:

```
<select id="box1" name="selectArea">
<option value="98">dog</option>
<option value="7122">cat</option>
<option value="142">bird</option>
</select>
```

and this is my jQuery code:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("selectArea")[0];
var selected = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
```

The value of this is always wrong because there is no "selected" attribute in the options. In my case, I am using a new form and users have the option to select a value. When they select an option, the "selected" attribute doesn't get appended to the option automatically.

How would I go about choosing the option that's selected without the actual selected attribute? Is this even possible? When I select another option in the dropdown, the value of x.selectedIndex does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery you can get value of selected option simply with `$("[name='selectArea']").val()`

```js
var option = $("[name='selectArea']").val();

console.log(option);

$("[name='selectArea']").on('change', function(){
  var option = $("[name='selectArea']").val();
  console.log(option);
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
  alert($("[name='selectArea'] option:selected").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="box1" name="selectArea">
<option value="98">dog</option>
<option value="7122">cat</option>
<option value="142">bird</option>
</select>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: When I change the value of option and run the code again, option doesn't change. So, I can't get 7122 or 142 to show up when running the code snippet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @LewlSauce you have to write above code inside the change event.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks so much man! Going to get this implemented on my side and I think this should do the trick. Many thanks! If you don't mind me asking, I'm basically using a button to output the value of the selected option to the console. Rather than outputting to console on change, is there a way I could have the button determine the current value when it's pressed?

Comment: Rather than outputting to console on change, is there a way I could have a button determine the current value of the option when the button is pressed?

Comment: Yeah, so when the user clicks on the button, it pops up an alert displaying the value of the selected option.

Comment: @LewlSauce I have updated snippet, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I think so. Will try when I get home and Mark as answer if it is. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178577/discussion-between-lewlsauce-and-kiran-shahi).

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected option text using jquery like this and you can get selected value by using val() function of jquery instead of text()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#box1").on('change', function(){
            var conceptName = $('#box1').find(":selected").text();
            var values = $('#box1').find(":selected").val(); // for get values
            alert(conceptName)
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="box1" name="selectArea">
<option value="98">dog</option>
<option value="7122">cat</option>
<option value="142">bird</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```